# How to parse API response correctly

Tags: php, laravel, api

My Problem is relatively simple:

I make an API call and get the following answer in response:

```
[{"RowKey":24764}]
```

The Content-Type I'm receiving is `text/html`

Somehow, I'm just not able to parse this correctly. neither `json_encode`or `json_decode`seems to help.

I'm trying to Map the object into my response class:

```
class ApiResponse {

  public $schedules = [];

}
```

with the json object mapper from: https://github.com/mintware-de/json-object-mapper

Comment: can you paste the the result of json_decode?have you got any error when you json_decode?

Comment: json_decode works fine https://3v4l.org/osr1H

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this test case:

```
$response = '[{"RowKey":24764}]';
$result = json_decode($response, true);
echo $result[0]['RowKey']; // Output: 24764
```

Comment: Mistake on my side... I kept using `$result[0]->RowKey`, yours works fine. thank you